# How can I check if a credit card has been decline in .NET code using the Paypal API

Tags: paypal

What method and property in the Paypal API can I use to set an error code to simulate a declined credit card?

Or if there another way to do it via using a credit card in the sandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually there's specific card and CSV numbers too simulate the responses. Read [the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com) it will be in there.

Comment: See for this "Testing Error Conditions" at https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_Sandbox_UserGuide/testing_error_conditions.html

Answer (score 0):

You can see a full list of the paypal response codes [here](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_errorcodes#id09C3GA00GR1).

Assuming you are using a direct payment call, there's a few possible decline reasons but you probably want 15005 or 15006 - or just a short message response of "Processor Decline".

Answer (score 0):

For those using **Payflow Pro**, chapter 5 of [the official documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_PayflowPro_Guide.pdf) contains the credit card numbers used, and more importantly, the codes you'll receive for each status.

These codes are different than the 5-character PayPal codes returned by the previously mentioned documents. (Or at least I can't find the simpler codes).